# Combine two dict into one at different levels of indent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python3 code
how to combine two dictionaries 'd','dconn' in one, if they are in different levels indent.
I newbie in python3, help me please.

code approximately looks like that:

```
for ip in fp.read().splitlines():
    d={}
    if p.poll():
        d.update({ip : '1'}) 
    else:
        d.update({ip : '0'})

    for keys, value in d.items():
        print(keys, value)


dconn = {}
if connection.username == 'REPORT': 
    dconn.update({connection.username : '0'}) 
else:
    dconn.update({connection.username : '1'}) 

for keys, value in dconn.items():
    print(keys, value)
```

Comment: You can update one `dict` with antoher through the `update` function. If the indent levels don't match, just move both dictionaries to the same indentation level.

Comment: `dconn.update(d)`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make d Global and then concatenate both dictionaries like so:

```
newDict = dict(d.items() + dconn.items())
```

or to add one dictionary into another do:

```
dict.update(dict2)
```

Comment: Just thought he wants a new variable... if not update is indeed the faster solution ;)